# SVG - Calculating angle direction inside triangle

Tags: jquery, html, svg, geometry, angle

I'm trying to draw a triangle and his angles on svg, my problem is that I don't know how to 'decide' the angle direction. They should point to the center to the triangle and not the other way.

Take a look at this example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybaruchel/tdovywm0/

For now I just hard-coded it in these lines:

```
/** Calculating the direction of the angle **/
var x_arc_dir = 1;
var y_arc_dir = 1;
var z_arc_dir = 1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are we supposed to do in order to recreate the problem you're having?

Comment: just submit the form in the link I provided, you will see that some of the angles are upside down..

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the start and end angles:

```
var y_arc_end_x = (x1 - y1) - (x1 / 1.5) + parseInt(y1 * 1.67);
var y_arc_start_x   = (z1 - y1) - (z1 / 1.5) + parseInt(y1 * 1.67);

var y_arc_end_y = (x2 - y2) - (x2 / 1.5) + parseInt(y2 * 1.67);
var y_arc_start_y   = (z2 - y2) - (z2 / 1.5) + parseInt(y2 * 1.67);
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rouzrtpt/

Comment: Sorry but this way doesnt work because if you try changing the input values the problem still exists.. Thanks anyways

Comment: Try reverting the values of the input boxes.. You will see :)

Comment: It depends on how you change... I believe you're gonna need a different algorithm if you want to cover any possible 3-points option.